# Blender file increases dramatically, when bending complex objects

Tags: objects, transforms, blend-files, groups, memory-management

My project consists of complex objects, it visualizes architecture. When one of the complex objects I join (<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), the Blender file increases dramatically from 500 MB to 2.5 GB.

Can anything be done about it?

The second question stems from the above problem. I combined these objects because I want to use a simple deform - bend.

How to do it without joining objects?
The photo shows the bend effect but the Blender file is very large.

[image: Bend effect]

Comment: Hard to say why joining two objects increases the size dramatically. One reason could be, that the object consuming another, has shape keys, and so it duplicates added vertices for all shape keys. There could be a similar interaction with a physics simulation, but I doubt any of those two scenarios are the case here.